# PHP session being lost

Tags: php, jquery, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I'm trying to implement and authentication system with jQuery and PHP. All the php work is made in the controller and datahandler class. There is no php code inside the .html files, all the values in .html files are rendered via jQuery that request the data from php server. So what I'm trying to do is:

1. When user clicks the login button, the jQuery makes a call to the authenticate() method in my controller class, it checks if the user is correct and stuff, and if it is, start the session and set the user_id on the session so I can access it later, and returns the userId to the jQuery client again.
2. After that, if everything is fine, in jQuery I redirect it to the html file. On the html file I call a jQuery from the `<script>` tag that will handle other permissions. But this jQuery will access the method getPermissionString (from the same class of `authenticate()` method mentioned before), and it will need to get the session value set in authenticate method.

**The Problem:**

When I try to get the session value inside `getPermissionString()` it says:

> Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION

I've tried to check if the session is registered in the second method, but looks like it's not. Here is my PHP code.

Any idea? Thanks.

```
public function authenticate($login, $password)
{
    $result = $this->userDataHandler->authenticateUser($login, $password);

    if(is_numeric($result) && $result != 0) 
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["uid"] = $result;

        if(isset($_SESSION["uid"]))
        {
            echo "registered";
            $userId = $_SESSION["uid"]; 
        }
        else
        {
            echo "not registered";  
        }

        echo $result;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 0; 
    }
}

public function getPermissionString()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION["uid"]))
    {
        echo "registered";
        $userId = $_SESSION["uid"]; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo "not registered";  
    }
}
```

Comment: `$_SESSION` is undefined unless the session has started. Start the session and you're fine.

Comment: @hakre but I'm starting it as you can see.

Comment: Have you tried putting session_start() outside the function? maybe top of top of the page that is being called by jquery?

Comment: As the error shows (and as I can see) you are **not** starting a session. So please don't try to blend me.

Comment: @JA but I dont think that will fit my problem, since that will be called no matter the user is authenticated or not, right?

Comment: Back to school, take a re-read of what sessions in PHP are: http://php.net/sessions

Comment: @hakre please see in the line 7 I call the session_start() method.

Comment: @rogcg: You know what, there *was* a Apollo mission that landed on the moon. But after that mission there were others that weren't. The NASA did not try to tell everybody they always managed to go there only because they did it once. It's similar with your sessions. Only because there is some `session_start` somewhere in your code it does not mean that the session is started.

Comment: Codeigniter has some of the best PHP session control with security. [Check it out](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: @rogcg: actually, It looks like you're passing an Array into the is_numeric argument and it's returning false, because Array's don't return true under the scope of is_numeric.

Comment: @hakre as you can see, right after the session_start() method call, I check if it is registered, and it says it is. But when I try to access from another method, it says it's not.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy no. the result variable returns an int by the datahandler code. I just didn't post the datahandler code here, but I've tested and that variable returns an int. =)

Comment: @rogcg: What everyone is trying to say is : session_start is not like initializing another global variable. It is better to put it on top of page preferably before any header information is sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can access `$_SESSION` in the second function you need to ensure that the program has called `session_start()` beforehand. The global variable is only populated when the session has been activated. If you never remember to start a session before using it then you can change the php.ini variable below:

```
[session]
session.auto_start = 1
```

Further, you said that you're using a class for your code. In this case you can also autos tart your session each time the class in created by using magic methods:

```
class auth {
  function __construct() {
    session_start();
  }
  function yourfunction() {
    ...
  }
  function yoursecondfunction(){
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Further, you said that your code is in a class. You can use magic methods to auto start the session each time the class is created:

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have [session.auto_start](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) enabled, and *authenticate* and *getPermissionString* are called on two different requests, you need to call [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) in each function.

If you need more information on how the session ID is passed, just read [Passing the Session ID](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use that function if session is not started. So throw an exception:

```
public function getPermissionString()
{
    if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
    {
        throw new Exception('No active session found.');
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION["uid"]))
    {
        echo "registered";
        $userId = $_SESSION["uid"]; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo "not registered";  
    }
}
```

This ensures the pre-conditions of your functions are checked inside the function so you don't need to check it each time before calling the function.

You will now see an exception if you wrongly use that function and it will give you a backtrace so you can more easily analyze your code.

Answer (score 0):

For php sessions to work you have to call `session_start()` every time you script is requested by the browser.